# What are differences about equi join and inner join?

Tags: oracle11gr2

I'm using Oracle 11g for the study. Now, I don't understand the below example because, SQL result is same. I want to listen about join differences above example

```
SELECT P.player_name,
       P.back_no,
       T.region_name,
       T.team_name
FROM   player P
       inner join team T
               ON P.team_id = T.team_id
                  AND P.position = 'GK'
ORDER  BY P.back_no ASC;

SELECT P.player_name,
       P.back_no,
       T.region_name,
       T.team_name
FROM   player P
       inner join team T
               ON P.team_id = T.team_id
WHERE  P.position = 'GK'
ORDER  BY P.back_no ASC;
```

Comment: There is no difference. I personally find it confusing that the first form is allowed because the `= 'GK'` term is a filter on one of the input tables and doesn't have anything to do with the join operation per se.

Comment: If I remember my SQL curse correctly the SQL optimizer will first build the subresult via `P.position = 'GK'` anyway before the join to reduce the result of temporarly rows for the query. But I'm not quite sure if the `p.team_id = T.team_id` term is used in this step at once or if it's a seperate step.

Comment: i know that inner join should have join condition. finally, "FROM ~ INNER JOIN ~ ON ~" is one step(FROM). thx :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the below link might help you to understand the difference. [Read Here](http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/What-s-the-difference-between-an-SQL-inner-join-and-equijoin).

> Almost every join is an equijoin, because the condition for matching rows is based on the equality of two values—one from each of the tables being joined. So that's what makes it an equijoin: the ON condition is equality. This includes inner joins and all three types of outer joins.
>
> Inner joins, on the other hand, can be based on equality to match rows, or on some other condition entirely. If it's not an equijoin, then it's usually called a theta join, although to be precise, an equijoin is just one of the possible theta joins; other theta joins use less than, less than or equal, etc., as the comparison operator. As long as the comparison evaluates to TRUE, the matched rows qualify for the join.

You can find the examples in the above mentioned link.